# unable to append input text to <li> tag on submit

Tags: jquery, html

When I alert the value, it is showing the correct string but when appended to `<li>` tag, it is shown as `[object,object]`

Code:

```
$('.ic_table').on('click', function()
   {
      var primaryData_Input = $('.form-control').val();
       alert(primaryData_Input);
       $('#datamodelArea').append('<div id="divDT1" class="dataModelTable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"><div class="dataTableName">'+ {text: primaryData_Input} +'</div><div class="widget"><div class="widget-head"> <a href="#" id="toggle1" class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-1x attributes"><i></i></a> Attributes </div><div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1"></div></div></div>');
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating object in your code, just concatenate string instead. Change `{text: primaryData_Input}` to `primaryData_Input`.

**Update :** 
As per your comment generating unique id, add a variable and concatenate it with id then increment the value

```
var i=0;
$('.ic_table').on('click', function() {
  var primaryData_Input = $('.form-control').val();
  alert(primaryData_Input);
  $('#datamodelArea').append('<div id="divDT' + i++ + '" class="dataModelTable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"><div class="dataTableName">' + primaryData_Input + '</div><div class="widget"><div class="widget-head"> <a href="#" id="toggle1" class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-1x attributes"><i></i></a> Attributes </div><div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1"></div></div></div>');
});
```

Comment: @Satyadev : glad to help

Comment: Got one more question. How do I append `<div id="divDT1` on submit the second time.

Comment: Yes I figured that out but how do I make it unique via jquery. All css styles are externally written by my UI team

Comment: Set a varaible and increment it on each click event

Comment: So it would be like: `$('#datamodelArea').append('<div id="divDT1"', i++, '</div>)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to just append the value of the input to the string like

```
$('#datamodelArea').append('<div id="divDT1" class="dataModelTable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"><div class="dataTableName">'+ primaryData_Input +'</div><div class="widget"><div class="widget-head"> <a href="#" id="toggle1" class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-1x attributes"><i></i></a> Attributes </div><div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1"></div></div></div>');
```

Your code is creating an object(`{text: primaryData_Input}`) and is using that object in string concatenation, whose default [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) implementation returns `[object,object]`